# Controller undefined in Karma-Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

So, I have been stumbling in this strange error for a couple of days by now. Hope you guys could help shedding some light in this tunnel. I'm really sorry to bother you with this, but the error log is not helping. Moreover a similar file (I can provide it if needed) has the same tests, written in the same way, and they works flawlessly.

I have been unit testing in karma-jasmine my project. Everything goes smoothly except for this file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.parkinput', ['ngRoute', 'Parklot', 'City','ngFileUpload'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/parkinput', {
    templateUrl: 'parkinput/parkinput.html',
    controller: 'parkinputCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('parkinputCtrl', ['$scope', 'NgMap', 'Parklot', 'City', '$location','Upload','$window', function($scope, NgMap, Parklot, City, $location,Upload,$window) {

  $scope.googleMapsUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY";

  var map;

  $scope.newParkZone = {};
  $scope.newPicture = {};
  $scope.marker = {id:'newParkZone', name: 'newParkZone', position:null};

  $scope.cities = City.getCities().then(
    function(response){
       $scope.cities = response.data;
    },
    function(error){
       console.log(error);
    });

  NgMap.getMap().then(
    function(evtMap) {
       map = evtMap;
    },
    function(error){
      //console.log(error);
    });

  $scope.setCenter = function(event, city) {
    if(city)
    {
       //preparing the latlen obj to change the map center
       var coords = $scope.newParkZone.City.GPS_Coordinates_Center.split(",");
      map.setCenter({
         lat : coords[0]*1,
         lng : coords[1]*1
      });
      return;
     }
     map.setCenter(event.latLng);
     $scope.marker.position = event.latLng;
     $scope.newParkZone.coords = event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng();
  };

  $scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.newParkZone.picture = "";
    var newParklot = Parklot.create($scope.newParkZone);
    if ($scope.upload_form.file.$valid && $scope.file) { 
      $scope.upload($scope.file, newParklot); //call upload function
    }
  }

  $scope.upload = function (file, parklot) {
    Upload.upload({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/image', 
      data:{file:file, parklot:parklot} 
    }).then(
      function (resp) {
        if(resp.data.error_code === 0){ 
          $window.alert('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ');
        } else {
          $window.alert('an error occured');
        }
      },
      function (resp) { 
        $window.alert('Error status: ' + resp.status);
      });
  };

}]);
```

that should be tested like follows:

```
describe('Park Input Module', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp.parkinput'));

    describe('Route Configuration', function() {
        var $scope = null;
        var ctrl = null;

        it('should be correct', function() {

            inject(function($route, $location, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {

                expect($route.current).toBeUndefined();

                $httpBackend.expectGET('parkinput/parkinput.html').respond(200);
                $location.path('/parkinput');
                $rootScope.$digest();

                expect($route.current.templateUrl).toBe('parkinput/parkinput.html');
                expect($route.current.controller).toBe('parkinputCtrl');

            });
        }); 
    });

    describe('controller', function(){
        var $controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope){
            $controller = _$controller_;
        }));

        it('should be defined', function(){
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('parkinputCtrl', { $scope: $scope});
            expect(controller).toBeDefined()
        });
    })

});
```

Here goes the errors:

`

```
Firefox 59.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Park Input Module Route Configuration should be correct FAILED
        minErr/<@node_modules/angular/angular.js:116:12
        loadModules/<@node_modules/angular/angular.js:5023:15
        forEach@node_modules/angular/angular.js:408:11
        loadModules@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4983:5
        createInjector@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4900:19
        WorkFn@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3173:44
        angular.mock.inject@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3153:35
        @app/parkinput/parkinput.spec.js:11:13
        <Jasmine>
Firefox 59.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Park Input Module controller should be defined FAILED
        minErr/<@node_modules/angular/angular.js:116:12
        loadModules/<@node_modules/angular/angular.js:5023:15
        forEach@node_modules/angular/angular.js:408:11
        loadModules@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4983:5
        createInjector@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4900:19
        WorkFn@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3173:44
        <Jasmine>
        TypeError: $controller is not a function in app/parkinput/parkinput.spec.js (line 35)
        @app/parkinput/parkinput.spec.js:35:30
        <Jasmine>
```

`

Again, forgive me for the WoT, but I am clueless. I can provide karma configuration file if needed. Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: did you declare your files one by one in karma config file? there are a lot of errors caused by asterisk definitions.

Comment: @AliBahrami, yes, as you can see in this short version:

files: [
      //ANGULAR
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',                             
      './node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      './app/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js',
      './app/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js',
      './app/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.js',
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      './app/parkinput/parkinput.js',
      './app/parkinput/parkinput.spec.js'
    ]